# Radio button styles not getting changed

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement custom styles for radio buttons.

I've almost achieved it but issue is when i try to click on other radio button it is not getting highlighted.

I'm struck here please help.

```css
.radio-radio-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked+span>label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-lg-12 radioBlock">
  <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Capacity" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">Capacity &amp; Partial Service</label></span>
  </span><span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Prod" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">Full Network Service (No Capacity)</label></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the unique `id`'s. Both `id`'s are radio1. You should set it to *radio1* and *radio2* and so on.

And don't forget the labels `for` property to link to the correct `input` field. See below.

```css
.radio-radio-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked+span>label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-lg-12 radioBlock">
  <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Capacity" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">Capacity &amp; Partial Service</label></span>
  </span><span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Prod" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio2">Full Network Service (No Capacity)</label></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfectly working code for your quick reference

```css
.radio-radio-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked+span>label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 12px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-lg-12 radioBlock">
  <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Capacity" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">Capacity &amp; Partial Service</label></span>
  </span><span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Prod" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio2">Full Network Service (No Capacity)</label></span>
  </span>
</div>
```